# Boost::Lexical_cast conversion to float changes data

Tags: c++, boost, floating-point, lexical-cast

I am receiving data from MySQL and try to play with it. The data received is in `m_caracs` and then I try to cut every sub-parts of this stream in other `float`.

Let's see the code :

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::string m_sten;
std::string m_feal;
std::string m_felt;
std::string m_inte;
std::string m_sag;
std::string m_ende;
std::string m_asko;
std::string m_vit;

void test(bool mon)
{
    std::string m_caracs = "f21.0i51.24v58.65c47.3s5.54d57.68e54.23h24.42";
    if (mon == 0)
    {
        std::vector<std::string> charmps;
        boost::split(charmps, m_caracs, boost::is_any_of("fivcsdeh"));
        m_sten = boost::lexical_cast<float>(charmps[1]);
        m_feal = boost::lexical_cast<float>(charmps[2]);
        m_felt = boost::lexical_cast<float>(charmps[3]);
        m_inte = boost::lexical_cast<float>(charmps[4]);
        m_sag = boost::lexical_cast<float>(charmps[5]);
        m_ende = boost::lexical_cast<float>(charmps[6]);
        m_asko = boost::lexical_cast<float>(charmps[7]);
        m_vit = boost::lexical_cast<float>(charmps[8]);
        std::cout << m_caracs << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << m_caracs << std::endl;
        m_caracs = "f" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(m_sten) +
                   "i" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(m_feal) +
                   "v" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(m_felt) +
                   "c" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(m_inte) +
                   "s" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(m_sag) +
                   "d" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(m_ende) +
                   "e" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(m_asko) +
                   "h" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(m_vit);
        std::cout << m_caracs << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    test(1);
    test(0);
}
```

You can see that `f21.0i51.24v58.65c47.3s5.54d57.68e54.23h24.42` becomes `f21.0i51.24v58.65c47.3s5.54d57.68e54.23h24.42`. This is exactly what I want. The problem is, I have that :

[image]

I don't know where it comes from. The only change is that `m_caracs` is a stream received from a database. Is that a conversion problem ?

Comment: I think your globals `m_*` should be `floats` (and you wanted to call `test(0)` before `test(1)`)

Comment: Oups, forgot to edit, they are, sorry. I'm reading your code at the moment. Thank you, sehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that one time you treat the split tokens as strings (leaving them unchanged), and sometimes you convert to float.

The conversion to float creates an *inexact* binary floating point representation.

To avoid it, don't use a binary floating point representation, but use a decimal representation with sufficient precision to accurately store your decimal input representation.

Use, e.g. `boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float`

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15b6c2eaf1684048)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
typedef boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50 Float;

int main()
{
    std::string const m_caracs("f21.0i51.24v58.65c47.3s5.54d57.68e54.23h24.42");
    std::cout << m_caracs << '\n';

    Float m_sten, m_feal, m_felt, m_inte, m_sag, m_ende, m_asko, m_vit;

    //auto num = qi::as_string[qi::raw[qi::double_]]; // this would parse exponents like 57.68e54
    auto num = boost::proto::deep_copy(qi::as_string[+qi::char_("-+0-9.")]);
    if (qi::parse(m_caracs.begin(), m_caracs.end(),
                'f' >> num >> 'i' >> num >> 'v' >> num >>
                'c' >> num >> 's' >> num >> 'd' >> num >>
                'e' >> num >> 'h' >> num,
                m_sten, m_feal, m_felt, m_inte, m_sag, m_ende, m_asko, m_vit
             ))
    {
        std::cout <<
            'f' << m_sten <<
            'i' << m_feal <<
            'v' << m_felt <<
            'c' << m_inte <<
            's' << m_sag  <<
            'd' << m_ende <<
            "e" << m_asko <<
            'h' << m_vit  << '\n';
    }
}
```

**PS** Note there is also a problem with the input format! `57.68e54` is a valid floating point number (e.g. for `lexical_cast`). Also, there could be issues with `NaN` or `Inf`

Note: in the example above you'd probably want to use `qi::real_parser<Float, custom_real_policies<Float> >` to parse directly into a `cpp_dec_float`, and not recognizing an exponent (like `e54`)

Comment: Well, seems to work well, but I did a misstake : I just need to work with integer... So, well, hank you again sehe for your attention. Hope it will helps someone then !